# Failed to initialize tcti context

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, tpm

Finding information for TPM2 and even worse for Ubuntu 18.04 server is quite a drill. I have a machine with an intel TPM V2 module onboard and basically trying to have it unlock LUKS on boot. So far I have the following

- Installed Ubuntu 18.04 server (with LVM and encrypted rootfs)
- Installed the tpm2-tools
- Enabled and started the resource manager service (status checks running all fine)
- set TPM2TOOLS_TCTI to `/dev/tpmrm0`
- Trying to take ownership (and most other tpm2_ commands fail with `Failed to initialize tcti context: 0x1`

This is where I'm stuck.

```
# apt install tmp2-tools
# systemctl enable tpm2-resourcemgr
# systemctl start tpm2-resourcemgr
# export TPM2TOOLS_TCTI=device:/dev/tpmrm0
# tpm2_takeownership -e 123 -o 123 -l 123
Failed to initialize tcti context: 0x1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the combined TPM2TOOLS_TCTI environment variable is new in tpm2-tools v3.0. Older versions used to use separate settings `TPM2TOOLS_TCTI_NAME=device` and `TPM2TOOLS_DEVICE_FILE=/dev/tpm0`.

Second, there are three ways to access the TPM 2.0 device:

1. Directly, through TCTI `device` and path `/dev/tpm0`. This is limited to one process at a time, and that process needs to clean up after itself (flush temporary handles, etc). This method would work just fine for LUKS usage.
2. Through the kernel resource manager, TCTI `device` and path `/dev/tpmrm0`. This requires a relatively recent kernel.
3. Through the userspace resource manager. On modern systems this would normally be TCTI `abrmd` (with no path), available in the 'tpm2-abrmd' package – and the service would also be "tpm2-abrmd".

   Ubuntu 18.04 ships a very old version of the Intel TPM2 stack – its "tpm2-resourcemgr" seems to work completely differently (there's no matching tcti library as far as I can see). I would avoid using this old service.

If you use the kernel resource manager (the `tpmrm0` device), you **do not** need a userspace resource manager. And vice versa, if you use a userspace resource manager (abrmd), then it's the one which claims exclusive access to /dev/tpm0 and I think that means you *should not* use /dev/tpmrm0 either.

So in your case, I think you should:

1. Stop and disable `tpm2-resourcemgr.service`
2. Unset TPM2TOOLS_TCTI
3. Set TPM2TOOLS_TCTI_NAME to `device`
4. Set TPM2TOOLS_DEVICE_FILE to `/dev/tpmrm0` if you want to use the kernel RM (or `/dev/tpm0` otherwise)

If nothing works, there is also another TPM 2.0 stack by IBM, available as the 'tss2' package. Both offer mostly the same operations and both can be used with the same TPM device. (Note that the IBM tools use different envvars, and require TPM_INTERFACE_TYPE set to `dev`.)

Comment: I tried Clevis with TPM on Ubuntu 18.04 pretty outdated packages there too. Rumour has it 20.04 release works better. Fingers crossed. Until then I'll pursue the manual path to further explore the toolset.

Comment: I don't know how Clevis works, but beware that the Intel tpm2-tools suite often has _massive_ changes in its CLI syntax between major releases, so e.g. scripts and tutorials written for v2.x will be incompatible with 4.x and vice versa. I don't know about v1.x but it's probably also different